# Cassandra: Can't start service with error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to contact any seeds

Tags: centos6.4, cassandra

System info:

Linux stg-univ-cassandra06 2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 16 18:37:12 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Cassandra version: 2.0.1
JVM vendor/version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.7.0_25

It might have something to do with

```
WARN 16:25:22,580 Detected previous bootstrap failure; retrying
```

But I'm not sure. Trying looking up this problem a lot but couldn't find anything.

Below is the log:

```
xss =  -ea -javaagent:./../lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms8192M -Xmx8192M -Xmn2048M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss256k
[root@stg-univ-cassandra01 bin]#  INFO 16:53:27,972 Logging initialized
 INFO 16:53:27,994 JVM vendor/version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.7.0_25
 INFO 16:53:27,994 Heap size: 8375238656/8375238656
 INFO 16:53:27,995 Classpath: ./../conf:./../build/classes/main:./../build/classes/thrift:./../lib/antlr-3.2.jar:./../lib/apache-cassandra-2.0.1.jar:./../lib/apache-cassandra-clientutil-2.0.1.jar:./../lib/apache-cassandra-thrift-2.0.1.jar:./../lib/commons-cli-1.1.jar:./../lib/commons-codec-1.2.jar:./../lib/commons-lang3-3.1.jar:./../lib/compress-lzf-0.
8.4.jar:./../lib/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.3.jar:./../lib/disruptor-3.0.1.jar:./../lib/guava-15.0.jar:./../lib/high-scale-lib-1.1.2.jar:./../lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar:./../lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar:./../lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar:./../lib/jbcrypt-0.3m.jar:./../lib/jline-1.0.jar:./../lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:./../lib/libthrift-0.9.1.jar:./../lib/
log4j-1.2.16.jar:./../lib/lz4-1.1.0.jar:./../lib/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:./../lib/netty-3.6.6.Final.jar:./../lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:./../lib/slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar:./../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.jar:./../lib/snakeyaml-1.11.jar:./../lib/snappy-java-1.0.5.jar:./../lib/snaptree-0.1.jar:./../lib/thrift-server-0.3.2.jar:./../lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar
 INFO 16:53:27,997 JNA not found. Native methods will be disabled.
 INFO 16:53:28,014 Loading settings from file:/opt/dsc-cassandra-2.0.1/conf/cassandra.yaml
 INFO 16:53:28,403 Data files directories: [/var/lib/cassandra/data]
 INFO 16:53:28,404 Commit log directory: /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog
 INFO 16:53:28,404 DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap
 INFO 16:53:28,404 disk_failure_policy is stop
 INFO 16:53:28,410 Global memtable threshold is enabled at 1996MB
 INFO 16:53:28,542 Not using multi-threaded compaction
 INFO 16:53:28,772 Initializing key cache with capacity of 100 MBs.
 INFO 16:53:28,781 Scheduling key cache save to each 14400 seconds (going to save all keys).
 INFO 16:53:28,782 Initializing row cache with capacity of 0 MBs
 INFO 16:53:28,789 Scheduling row cache save to each 0 seconds (going to save all keys).
 INFO 16:53:28,898 Initializing system.schema_triggers
 INFO 16:53:28,923 Initializing system.batchlog
 INFO 16:53:28,928 Initializing system.peer_events
 INFO 16:53:28,934 Initializing system.compactions_in_progress
 INFO 16:53:28,939 Initializing system.hints
 INFO 16:53:28,945 Initializing system.schema_keyspaces
 INFO 16:53:28,951 Opening /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_keyspaces/system-schema_keyspaces-jb-7 (213 bytes)
 INFO 16:53:28,951 Opening /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_keyspaces/system-schema_keyspaces-jb-5 (214 bytes)
 INFO 16:53:28,953 Opening /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_keyspaces/system-schema_keyspaces-jb-6 (214 bytes)
 INFO 16:53:28,984 Initializing system.range_xfers
 INFO 16:53:28,990 Initializing system.schema_columnfamilies
 INFO 16:53:28,993 Opening /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columnfamilies/system-schema_columnfamilies-jb-5 (5128 bytes)
 INFO 16:53:28,995 Opening /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columnfamilies/system-schema_columnfamilies-jb-7 (5121 bytes)
 INFO 16:53:28,995 Opening /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columnfamilies/system-schema_columnfamilies-jb-6 (5119 bytes)
 INFO 16:53:29,005 Initializing system.NodeIdInfo
 INFO 16:53:29,009 Initializing system.paxos
 INFO 16:53:29,015 Initializing system.schema_columns
 INFO 16:53:29,020 Opening /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columns/system-schema_columns-jb-7 (9124 bytes)
 INFO 16:53:29,020 Opening /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columns/system-schema_columns-jb-6 (9127 bytes)
 INFO 16:53:29,020 Opening /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columns/system-schema_columns-jb-5 (9138 bytes)
 INFO 16:53:29,028 Initializing system.IndexInfo
 INFO 16:53:29,033 Initializing system.peers
 INFO 16:53:29,039 Initializing system.local
 INFO 16:53:29,041 Opening /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/local/system-local-jb-29 (5719 bytes)
 INFO 16:53:29,575 Enqueuing flush of Memtable-local@483893872(114/1140 serialized/live bytes, 4 ops)
 INFO 16:53:29,578 Writing Memtable-local@483893872(114/1140 serialized/live bytes, 4 ops)
 INFO 16:53:29,622 Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/local/system-local-jb-30-Data.db (142 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1389254009487, position=289)
 INFO 16:53:29,669 Initializing system_traces.sessions
 INFO 16:53:29,673 Initializing system_traces.events
 INFO 16:53:29,675 completed pre-loading (1 keys) key cache.
 INFO 16:53:29,684 Replaying /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-3-1389252321162.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-3-1389252321163.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-3-1389252321164.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-3-1389252321165.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-3-1389252321166.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commit
log/CommitLog-3-1389252321167.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-3-1389252321168.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-3-1389252321169.log
 INFO 16:53:29,704 Replaying /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-3-1389252321162.log
 INFO 16:53:30,101 Finished reading /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-3-1389252321162.log
 INFO 16:53:30,102 Replaying /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-3-1389252321163.log
 INFO 16:53:30,102 Finished reading /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-3-1389252321163.log
 INFO 16:53:30,102 Replaying /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-3-1389252321164.log
 INFO 16:53:30,103 Finished reading /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-3-1389252321164.log
 INFO 16:53:30,103 Replaying /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-3-1389252321165.log
 INFO 16:53:30,103 Finished reading /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-3-1389252321165.log
 INFO 16:53:30,103 Replaying /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-3-1389252321166.log
 INFO 16:53:30,104 Finished reading /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-3-1389252321166.log
 INFO 16:53:30,104 Replaying /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-3-1389252321167.log
 INFO 16:53:30,105 Finished reading /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-3-1389252321167.log
 INFO 16:53:30,105 Replaying /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-3-1389252321168.log
 INFO 16:53:30,106 Finished reading /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-3-1389252321168.log
 INFO 16:53:30,106 Replaying /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-3-1389252321169.log
 INFO 16:53:30,106 Finished reading /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-3-1389252321169.log
 INFO 16:53:30,145 Enqueuing flush of Memtable-schema_keyspaces@1390398918(251/2510 serialized/live bytes, 8 ops)
 INFO 16:53:30,146 Writing Memtable-schema_keyspaces@1390398918(251/2510 serialized/live bytes, 8 ops)
 INFO 16:53:30,146 Enqueuing flush of Memtable-schema_columns@1665051819(45669/456690 serialized/live bytes, 1528 ops)
 INFO 16:53:30,147 Enqueuing flush of Memtable-schema_columnfamilies@666517876(25092/250920 serialized/live bytes, 802 ops)
 INFO 16:53:30,160 Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_keyspaces/system-schema_keyspaces-jb-8-Data.db (214 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1389254009487, position=289)
 INFO 16:53:30,161 Writing Memtable-schema_columns@1665051819(45669/456690 serialized/live bytes, 1528 ops)
 INFO 16:53:30,216 Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columns/system-schema_columns-jb-8-Data.db (9130 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1389254009487, position=289)
 INFO 16:53:30,217 Writing Memtable-schema_columnfamilies@666517876(25092/250920 serialized/live bytes, 802 ops)
 INFO 16:53:30,245 Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columnfamilies/system-schema_columnfamilies-jb-8-Data.db (5123 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1389254009487, position=289)
 INFO 16:53:30,246 Log replay complete, 44 replayed mutations
 INFO 16:53:30,269 Compacting [SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columns/system-schema_columns-jb-6-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columns/system-schema_columns-jb-8-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columns/system-schema_columns-jb-5-Data.db'), SSTableRead
er(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columns/system-schema_columns-jb-7-Data.db')]
 INFO 16:53:30,269 Compacting [SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columnfamilies/system-schema_columnfamilies-jb-6-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columnfamilies/system-schema_columnfamilies-jb-5-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columnfamilies/system-schema_
columnfamilies-jb-8-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columnfamilies/system-schema_columnfamilies-jb-7-Data.db')]
 INFO 16:53:30,269 Compacting [SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_keyspaces/system-schema_keyspaces-jb-6-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_keyspaces/system-schema_keyspaces-jb-5-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_keyspaces/system-schema_keyspaces-jb-8-Data.db')
 INFO 16:53:30,326 Compacted 4 sstables to [/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_keyspaces/system-schema_keyspaces-jb-9,].  855 bytes to 214 (~25% of original) in 53ms = 0.003851MB/s.  8 total rows, 2 unique.  Row merge counts were {1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:2, }
 INFO 16:53:30,369 Compacted 4 sstables to [/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columnfamilies/system-schema_columnfamilies-jb-9,].  20,491 bytes to 5,123 (~25% of original) in 97ms = 0.050368MB/s.  8 total rows, 2 unique.  Row merge counts were {1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:2, }
 INFO 16:53:30,410 Compacted 4 sstables to [/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columns/system-schema_columns-jb-9,].  36,519 bytes to 9,130 (~25% of original) in 139ms = 0.062641MB/s.  8 total rows, 2 unique.  Row merge counts were {1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:2, }
 INFO 16:53:30,736 Cassandra version: 2.0.1
 INFO 16:53:30,736 Thrift API version: 19.37.0
 INFO 16:53:30,740 CQL supported versions: 2.0.0,3.1.1 (default: 3.1.1)
 INFO 16:53:30,756 Loading persisted ring state
 INFO 16:53:30,759 Starting up server gossip
 INFO 16:53:30,779 Enqueuing flush of Memtable-local@137688436(286/2860 serialized/live bytes, 10 ops)
 INFO 16:53:30,780 Writing Memtable-local@137688436(286/2860 serialized/live bytes, 10 ops)
 INFO 16:53:30,793 Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/local/system-local-jb-31-Data.db (261 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1389254009487, position=161327)
 INFO 16:53:30,834 Starting Messaging Service on port 7000
 WARN 16:53:30,865 Detected previous bootstrap failure; retrying
 INFO 16:53:30,866 JOINING: waiting for ring information
 INFO 16:54:00,872 JOINING: schema complete, ready to bootstrap
 INFO 16:54:00,879 JOINING: getting bootstrap token
 INFO 16:54:00,917 Enqueuing flush of Memtable-local@747432494(10119/101190 serialized/live bytes, 259 ops)
 INFO 16:54:00,917 Writing Memtable-local@747432494(10119/101190 serialized/live bytes, 259 ops)
 INFO 16:54:00,944 Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/local/system-local-jb-32-Data.db (5323 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1389254009487, position=173440)
 INFO 16:54:00,946 Compacting [SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/local/system-local-jb-32-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/local/system-local-jb-30-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/local/system-local-jb-29-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/local/syste
m-local-jb-31-Data.db')]
 INFO 16:54:00,958 JOINING: sleeping 30000 ms for pending range setup
 INFO 16:54:00,997 Compacted 4 sstables to [/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/local/system-local-jb-33,].  11,445 bytes to 5,711 (~49% of original) in 48ms = 0.113467MB/s.  4 total rows, 1 unique.  Row merge counts were {1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:1, }
ERROR 16:54:30,961 Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to contact any seeds!
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.bootstrap(StorageService.java:899)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.joinTokenRing(StorageService.java:670)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:529)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:428)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:343)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:442)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:485)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to contact any seeds!
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.bootstrap(StorageService.java:899)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.joinTokenRing(StorageService.java:670)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:529)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:428)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:343)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:442)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:485)
Exception encountered during startup: Unable to contact any seeds!
ERROR 16:54:30,966 Exception in thread Thread[StorageServiceShutdownHook,5,main]
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.stopRPCServer(StorageService.java:312)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.shutdownClientServers(StorageService.java:361)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.access$000(StorageService.java:96)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService$1.runMayThrow(StorageService.java:494)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: What does nodetool ring show?